# Cumulative / Running total group by one column

Tags: sql, request, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate cumulative column. The result i want it's in 2nd table in column "Cumul_result".

I have this table :

[image]

I want to calculate Running total group by article.
For exemplace te result will be :
[image: | Article | YEAR |Quantity |Cumulative_result | -------- |-------- |-------------- |------------------| | 1 | 2022 |0 |0 | | 1 | 2023 |10 |10 | | 1 | 2024 |100 |110 | | 526 | 2020 |50 |50 | | 526 | 2021 |0 |0 | | 526 | 2022 |10 |60 | | 852 | 2021 |1 |1 | | 852 | 2020 |0 |1 |]

I try this request bu it's not work :

```
select Article,
       Year,
       Quantity ,
       Sum(Quantity) over ( order by  Year) as Cumul_result
  
FROM TABLE;
```

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't use images ! so it can be easy to reproduce your problem https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct, all you need to do is `partition by` Article:

```
select Article,
       Year,
       Quantity ,
       Sum(Quantity) over (partition by Article order by Year) as Cumul_result
FROM mytable;
```